# Angular module for handling request outcomes

Tags: angularjs, rest, controller, ng-controller

I'm working on an Angular controller, where on load make multiple async requests. First request `dataA` and `dataB`. If the first request is successful, and `dataA` is found, and based on it's property I request `dataC` and `dataD`. For each request I need to use a different service (services built on `$http`).

For each request I should display a spinner while loading, handle the case when the request times out (and provide a retry functionality for that component) plus handle the case when the object is not found.

In my current implementation I'm initializing a variable to hold the state values:

```
$scope.responses = {
    dataA: {
        loading: true
    },
    dataB: {
        loading: true
    },
    dataC: {
        loading: true
    },
    dataD: {
        loading: true
    }
};
```

The corresponding sample from my template:

```
<label>dataA (#{{ dataA.id }}) <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="responses.dataA.loading"></i></label>
<div ng-show="responses.dataA.success">
    <p>{{ dataA.preperty1 }} | {{ dataA.preperty2 }}</p>
</div>
<p class="error-message" ng-show="!responses.dataA.success && !loading.dataA">Failed to load dataA</p>
```

And the corresponding part of the controller:

```
function loadDataA(property0) {
    BackendService.get('dataA/pr0perty0/' + property0).then(function(data) {
        $scope.dataA = data;
        $scope.responses.dataA.success = true;

        if ($scope.dataA.id) {
            loadDataC(dataA.id);
            loadDataD(dataA.id);
        }
    }, function() {
        $scope.responses.dataA.success = false;
    }).finally(function() {
        $scope.responses.dataA.loading = false;
    });
}
```

So this code snippet is only for `dataA`, I have to do the same (basically copy pasting) for the rest.

I haven't added the retry functionality yet, but it already feels like something that could be extracted and is probably already implemented before.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/ThomasBurleson/angularjs-FlightDashboard - the last example talks about something similar.  In addition, add retry using - https://github.com/thaiat/angular-retry which gives you the flexibility of promises and retries and async/sync.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently I came up with a good enough solution with a helper function + a directive. The helper function is the following:

```
function promiseHandler(promise, responseState, successCallback) {
    responseState.loading = true;

    promise.then(function(data) {
        successCallback(data);
        responseState.success = true;
    }, function() {
        responseState.success = false;
    }).finally(function() {
        responseState.loading = false;
    });
}
```

Thus, the loader function can be simplified as follows:

```
promiseHandler(
BackendService.get('dataA/property0/' + property0),
$scope.responseStates.dataA,
function(data) {
    $scope.dataA = data;

    if ($scope.dataA.id) {
        loadDataC(dataA.id);
        loadDataD(dataA.id);
    }
});
```

Which looks much better I think. The directive looks like this:

```
.directive('requestSection', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: './request.section.directive.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            sectionClass: '@',
            label: '@',
            failureMessage: '@',
            responseState: '=',
            retryFunction: '&'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.retryDefined = 'retryFunction' in attrs;
        }
    };
}]);
```

With the following template:

```
<div class="section {{ sectionClass }}">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label>{{ label }} <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="responseState.loading"></i></label>
            <div ng-hide="responseState.loading">
                <div ng-hide="responseState.success">
                    <p class="error-message">{{ failureMessage }} <a href="" ng-if="retryDefined" ng-click="retryFunction()"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></a></p>
                </div>
                <div ng-show="responseState.success" ng-transclude></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This helped me refactoring a large part of the HTML code.

Any ideas for further improvement are welcome